# Code Contract gives null warning with ServiceLocator

Tags: c#, .net, code-contracts

Using  `HtmlPage.RegisterScriptableObject("Shell", serviceLocator.GetInstance<Shell>());`

gives me a null warning. How can I make this go away?

Answer (score 0):

The warning is that `serviceLocator` is null?

Without seeing any more of your code (to get an idea of what other contracts might be in play), you could put

```
Contract.Assume(serviceLocator != null);
```

on the line above.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps `serviceLocator.GetInstance<Shell>()` returns null if an instance is not found.

Try providing an alternative control flow for that situation.

```
var instance = serviceLocator.GetInstance<Shell>();
if (instance == null)
    throw new InvalidOperationException("Shell instance is missing.");
HtmlPage.RegisterScriptableObject("Shell", instance);
```